# handling the The CSRF token in symfony's forms when in public REST context

Tags: forms, rest, symfony, csrf, fosrestbundle

I'm developer my first symfony (3) app. it is a **REST service publicly accessible**.
I'm doing this using FOSRestBundle.
I'll have to ad some admin forms soon or later, and I'll probably want to create them directly (without passing by the extra work of consuming my own web services)

I wonder **how to handle the CSRF token in this case**. I see different solutions:

- globally deactivate the CSRF token : I don't want to do this
- create two set of forms, one with the token activated : form my admin forms, the other one for the REST API. => in this case, the rest API can't have a fallback _format=html
- find a way to give the api consumer an auth, with an API_GROUP, and disable the token for this group

  - it seem to me the best solution, but I don't know how to do it transparently, without affecting the auth of my future admin, and without needing to give credentials in the REST request.
- use an event listener in order to hack symfony's auth mechanism and give an auth if a call is made to the REST API (all but _format=html)

Which one of this (or other) solution seem the best to you, and how would you code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, perhaps not the best one, but it works :

```
$_format = $request->attributes->get('_format');
if ('html' == $_format) {
    $form = $this->createForm(ItopInstanceUserType::class, $itopInstanceUser);
} else {
    $form = $this->createForm(ItopInstanceUserType::class, $itopInstanceUser, ['csrf_protection' => false]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, forget CSRF token managed by yourself, check subjects like Oauth authentication.

Take a look here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

FOSOAuthServerBundle works perfectly with FOSRestBundle.

Comment: yes, but my API will be mainly accessed by a remotly hosted PHP/js program.

This remote program will access my API using ajax (jsonp/cors) calls.

For me, having to handle Oauth is a burden not a solution in this case, furthermore, the users of this prgramm won't know about the API, they won't have to configure it, it must work out of the box, so they would end using the same harcoded login/mdp.

What I mean is : the call won't need an auth. at all.